# Wordpress Yoast Breadcrumb code - Filter t change wrapper element

Tags: wordpress, function, plugins, filter, breadcrumbs

So the Yoast SEO plugin provides some handy stuff within Wordpress, one of these is the Breadcrumb functionality, however the markup output is within span tags (I added # for URLs - don't worry about that)...

```
<span xmlns:v="http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#">
    <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
        <a property="v:title" rel="v:url" href="#">Home</a>
    </span>
    <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
        <a property="v:title" rel="v:url" href="#">Our Services</a>
    </span>
    <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
        <a property="v:title" rel="v:url" href="#">GP Services</a>
    </span>
    <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
        <span property="v:title" class="breadcrumb_last">GP Appointments</span>
    </span>
</span>
```

I'd like to output the breadrcumbs as a list instead of these spans - so ultimately I think I need to add some sort of filter to my functions.php file - so when I update the Yoast SEO plugin down the line it doesn't overwrite my edits.

Within "/plugins/wordpress-seo/frontend/class-breadcrumbs.php" there is some code at the start where you can set the wrapper of the element.

Currently (minus comments and unrelated bits of code):

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'WPSEO_Breadcrumbs' ) ) {

    class WPSEO_Breadcrumbs {

        private $element = 'span';
```

So this is the part I need to overwrite with something in my theme's functions.php file.

I'm struggling with the markup for how to do this however.

There also seems to be a filter in this plugin file too:

```
private function filter_wrapper() {
    $wrapper = apply_filters( 'wpseo_breadcrumb_output_wrapper', $this->wrapper );
    $wrapper = tag_escape( $wrapper );
    if ( is_string( $wrapper ) && '' !== $wrapper ) {
        $this->wrapper = $wrapper;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I believe I found a solution -- my execution:

functions.php

```
function get_breadcrumb() {
    if ( function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb') ) {
        yoast_breadcrumb('<ol class="article__bread-crumb"><li>','</li></ol>');
    }
}
```

Then I call `get_breadcrumb()` wherever I need it in the theme.

Then in yoast settings, set the "separator between breadcrumbs" option to:

```
</li><li>
```

resulting code should end up like this:

```
<ol class="article__bread-crumb">
    <li>
        <span xmlns:v="http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#">
            <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
                <a href="[URL]/velonews" rel="v:url" property="v:title">Home</a>
            </span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span rel="v:child" typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
            <a href="[URL]/velonews/all" rel="v:url" property="v:title">All</a>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span rel="v:child" typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
            <a href="[URL]/velonews/category/news" rel="v:url" property="v:title">News</a>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="breadcrumb_last">Related Test</span>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. ended up getting a load of stray `</span>` tags in the last breadcrumb item: <li class="breadcrumb-item">`<span class="breadcrumb_last">Some Article Title</span></span></span></span></span></li>` - and no closing `</span>` in any of the others.

Comment: I don think this would validate, as the `xmlns span` is enclosed to early. However, without comment to deep, you coluld get this to work by calling the proper filters in the plugin instead of pasting html into options page.

Comment: This is smart, works for me. You can also add filter to set the separator, so the user cannot accidentally override the separator in settings and break your layout: `add_filter( 'wpseo_breadcrumb_separator', function() {  return '</li><li>'; }, 99);`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a simple way to do this, so I ended up just altering my CSS styles to account for the fact that instead of an unordered list, the elements were nested spans and links - not the end of the world, and a solution of sorts, but not really the solution I had in mind, sadly.

I'm sure there's a way to do this - but without help, I'm struggling.